# "Patronize this the _____" when talking about food

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There is a word in a video that I cannot figure out and have trouble hearing. The phrase as I hear it is (excuse me for inaccuracies):

> "Now don't be afraid to go out on into the lobby and patronize this the
>   **__** and buy some licorice sticks and mass pumpkin pie."

I'm assuming this is either an idiom that I am not aware of or he is talking about the place the film is being shown.

The [youtube video is here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMQ-t3nGzrI&=t=0m40s)

Comment: What they say is "this *theater*" (pronounced with a strong Texan accent as "thee-ayter"). They also say "*nice* pumpkin pie" (pronounced as "na-sce"). The strong accent is being put on for humorous effect, as cues such as the idea of buying a good ol' American pumpkin pie in a theater might suggest (though these cues may not be apparent to some people who do not hail from North America).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap - why don't you put that in an answer? I'd upvote it, it's a very good answer.

Comment: @Susan: done and done. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What they say is "this **theater**" (pronounced with a strong Texan accent as "*thee-ayter*"). They also say "**nice** pumpkin pie" (pronounced as "*na-sce*").

The strong accent is being put on for humorous effect, as cues such as the idea of buying a good ol' American pumpkin pie in a theater might suggest — though these cues might not be apparent to everyone who hasn't grown up immersed in American culture.

Comment: +1 - Your explanation of the Southern dialect is good, and obviously helpful to the OP. The few years I lives in the South (TN) I learned to say *hell* with three syllables. :) Anyway, welcome to EL&U, if you haven't been welcomed yet.

Comment: Thanks. I always wanted to do subtitles for the video, but I never was able to figure out what the word was. I have to admit the way he says `ayter` was throwing me off.

Comment: Even to me (Western Canadian), that pronounciation of *theater* sounds very much like two words. I pieced it together mainly from context and bits of media experience (*eg.* a childhood spent listening to the likes of Yosemite Sam).